# How a C array name save two values at one memory location?

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I am learning C array and confusing.

How an array name save two values at one memory location?

My sample code:

```
int main (){ 

    int a[2] = {1, 2}; 

    printf("&a = %p , &a[0] = %p\n", &a, &a[0]);
    printf("a = %p , a[0] = %d\n", a, a[0]);

}
```

Output:

```
&a = 0x7ffcd51df7e0 , &a[0] = 0x7ffcd51df7e0
a = 0x7ffcd51df7e0 , a[0] = 1
```

It shows that the **same address(0x7ffcd51df7e0)** (first output statement) saved **two
different values (0x7ffcd51df7e0 , 1)** (second output statement).

What C compiler do to make it happen or do I misunderstanding something?
Thanks!

Comment: Read about arrays and their properties before jumping into conclusions.

Comment: Which two *different* values are you referring to?

Comment: There is only one value stored in the array shown. Your question is unclear.

Comment: @Olaf It's not that much unclear. OP is confused for the output of second print statement.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Speculation. If he means something else, he will learn learn a wrong association, resulting in even more confusion.

Comment: How is it that you know enough to use `%p` to print an address value and `%d` for an integer but don't know the difference between a pointer and a dereference?  I think you're missing something fundamental here. :)

Comment: Thank you guys! Yes, I'm confused about the output of second statement. The array name "a" print  "0x7ffcd51df7e0" and "a[0]" print "1". I previous thought that   printf("%p", a):  is printing the value inside the memory of array name "a". Apparently, I am wrong > < .

Comment: @Olaf: "*There is only one value stored in the array shown.*" err, what please? I see two: `... = {1, 2};`

Comment: @alk: It should have been "printed".

Comment: The `printf` man page or any online documentation is very clear about this. The rest can be read in every C book.

Comment: @Olaf: Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operator, an expression of type "`N`-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element in the array.

Arrays in C do not store any metadata, so the address of the first element of the array and the address of the array itself are the same, something like the following:

```
   +---+
a: |   | a[0]
   +---+
   |   | a[1]
   +---+
```

This is why `&a` and `&a[0]` yield the same *value*; they both refer to the same memory location.  However, the *types* of the two expressions are different.  `&a` has type "pointer to 2-element array of `int`", or `int (*)[2]`.  `&a[0]` has type "pointer to `int`", or `int *` (think about the types of `a` and `a[0]` and this pattern will make sense).

Where things get weird is when `a` appears in an expression by itself.  If it's not the operand of either the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it's treated as a pointer to the first element of the array, and will be converted ("decay") to a pointer type.  This is why you got the output you did; `a`, `&a`, and `&a[0]` all evaluate to the address of the first element of the array.

Comment: Your answer is very clear, I better understand array now! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're mistaken.

When passed to a function as argument, the array name, `a` decays to a pointer to the first element. It does not represent the *value* of first element. You can get a *hint* of that by looking at their type and the corresponding format specifier used to print their values.

So,

```
printf("a = %p , a[0] = %d\n", a, a[0]);
```

is the same as

```
printf("a = %p , a[0] = %d\n", &a[0], a[0]);
```

If you want to get the value at address, you have to deference.

Comment: The name does not decay for the `&` operator! And OP clearly _does_ dereference.

Comment: @Olaf I think OP is asking for the understanding of output for second print statement, right?

Comment: Not sure. We need a [mcve] with expected outcome to know. And please don't state `a` and `&a[0]` are the same. You also have to convert the pointers for output to `void *`.

Comment: @Sourav Ghosh: Thank you! You know me well! ^^